# Headphones not detected when using an extension cord on Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, headphones, microphone

I have some regular wired USB-c earbuds that I bought from amazon. When I plug them in, they are immediately recognized on my MacBook Pro, and both input (mic) and output audio work perfectly fine. The problem is that they are too short. So I bought a USB-c extension cable.

When I try connecting these earbuds to my MacBook with the extension cable attached, they are never recognized by the machine. I hear a subtle electric sound when I plug them in, so I assume that means they are powered. But they don't show up in the settings either as an input (mic) method or output audio.

When I plug them into my old android device, however, they work perfectly fine including when using the extension cable. So I know this is a MacBook pro issue.

I tried restarting the machine and resetting the SMC, but neither worked.

Comment: Have you tried a different make of USB cable? MacOS (and Macs) are *very picky* with hardware and you may have run into a defective cable or a manufacturer with a cable design that is just enough different to not work. USB-C cables all look the same but sometime support only a subset of all the possible standards.

Comment: It works on my android device, so the cable is not defective. I only tried this cable, however. How do I know which cable is compatible with MacBooks? And why are they so picky/why don't they just work like normal hardware?

Comment: Not defective for your Android device, if it is not working on the Apple device it is defective *for your Apple device.* "Why" is not a question anyone outside of Apple can answer. Years of supporting Macs and PCs say that if a cable works on one device but not another, replace the cable.

Comment: Defective means that the cable has a defect, which it does not. The defect is in my Macbook Pro, which is unable to detect a perfectly fine cable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the cable is not defective, I am going to return it and order a different one because the Macbook is unable to identify it, even though my 2019 android and another Windows device can. There is no way to get this cable to work. Hopefully the next one I order will.

**Update**: I bought new ones, and they did NOT work, even though they worked on my android device and were advertised to be Macbook pro compatible. I'm sure this is an apple "feature".